# Parse JSON with wrong designed structure in Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary, parsing

I have to parse some really terrible designed JSON, and to be honest I have never faced with such one. The following is a simplified cut from the entire JSON file:

```
{
    "5ee70183-87fe-4799-802e-ef7f5e7323db": 
    {
        "title": "Bank 1",
        "logo": "655ee02d87cf4cdf912c3507233b0520.gif"
    },
    "332c7078-97ad-4bf7-b8ee-44d85a9c88d1": 
    {
        "title": "Bank 2",
        "logo": "655ee02d87cf4cdf912c3507233b0520.gif"
    },
    "8e9bd4c8-6f4a-4663-ae86-b8fbaf295030": 
    {
        "title": "Bank 3",
        "logo": "655ee02d87cf4cdf912c3507233b0520.gif"
    }
}
```

As you can see the "root" keys are some UUIDs. Those keys with values are supposed to be a list, but instead of using correct [] brackets for a list it's used {} wrong one. If I parse this using codables I have to create structs with UUID names, but what is worst this "list" is not fixed but go unlimited in theory. So my job is to parse this JSON and get an array of bank entities. As I'm shocked and confused at the moment I just think that I'm not able to use codables and need to parse this manually to a dictionary and get properties from there by assigning to the correct list item. If you ever faced with such an issue or know better parsing option, it will greatly help me to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
let res = try! JSONDecoder().decode([String:Root].self,from:data)
print(Array(res.values))
```

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
   let title, logo: String
}
```